# Failed to compile ./src/App.js Module not found

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, mamp

I am having a problem running my system on my local server.

I tried running `npm install` then `npm run start` then I start getting this error :

```
Failed to compile

./src/app/App.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'assets/css/style.css' in '/Volumes/Macbook Pro/02 - Business/03 - Projects/01 - All Clients/VS/MLM/03 - Source Codes/Live System/console/src/app'
```

I tried `npm install` `npm run build` then I get the following error :

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! console2@0.1.0 build: `npm run build-css && react-scripts build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the console2@0.1.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/av/.npm/_logs/2021-09-27T13_40_54_796Z-debug.log
```

I checked the logged file and I found this :

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/local/bin/node', '/usr/local/bin/npm', 'run', 'build' ]
2 info using npm@6.14.15
3 info using node@v14.17.6
4 verbose run-script [ 'prebuild', 'build', 'postbuild' ]
5 info lifecycle console2@0.1.0~prebuild: console2@0.1.0
6 info lifecycle console2@0.1.0~build: console2@0.1.0
7 verbose lifecycle console2@0.1.0~build: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle console2@0.1.0~build: PATH: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/Volumes/Macbook Pro/02 - Business/03 - Projects/01 - All Clients/VS/MLM/03 - Source Codes/Live System/console/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
9 verbose lifecycle console2@0.1.0~build: CWD: /Volumes/Macbook Pro/02 - Business/03 - Projects/01 - All Clients/VS/MLM/03 - Source Codes/Live System/console
10 silly lifecycle console2@0.1.0~build: Args: [ '-c', 'npm run build-css && react-scripts build' ]
11 silly lifecycle console2@0.1.0~build: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle console2@0.1.0~build: Failed to exec build script
13 verbose stack Error: console2@0.1.0 build: `npm run build-css && react-scripts build`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:400:28)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:400:28)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1055:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:288:5)
14 verbose pkgid console2@0.1.0
15 verbose cwd /Volumes/Macbook Pro/02 - Business/03 - Projects/01 - All Clients/VS/MLM/03 - Source Codes/Live System/console
16 verbose Darwin 18.7.0
17 verbose argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "build"
18 verbose node v14.17.6
19 verbose npm  v6.14.15
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error console2@0.1.0 build: `npm run build-css && react-scripts build`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the console2@0.1.0 build script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

I tried the following steps but I'm getting the same error :

```
npm cache clean --force
delete node_modules folder
delete package-lock.json file
sudo npm install npm@latest -g this will upgrade npm to latest version
npm audit fix --force
npm upgrade --force
npm install
```

Comment: Looks like a bad import path. Where are assets located?

Comment: @Morgan :  Assets is in my local folder. I did a `git pull master` from gitlab

Comment: Where are assets relative to App.js?

Comment: @Morgan: Inside my console local folder. here's the screenshot --> https://imgur.com/a/y7uVJwZ

Answer (score 0):

should `assets/css/style.css` be `../assets/css/style.css` or some other relative path depending on what file it is in?